# Why is there no channel logo on the LIVE cricket match?

Tags: m.s.-dhoni-untold-story

In [MS Dhoni The Untold Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.S._Dhoni:_The_Untold_Story), Dhoni and his roommates watch the 2003 World Cup Final Match.

But I didn't find any channel logo on the LIVE match.

[image]

I can sharply remember the 2003 World Cup Final Match telecasted on SET MAX channel in India.

Why is there no channel logo on the LIVE cricket match?

Comment: To avoid free endorsement to any TV channel.

Comment: This movie is BioPic. Not a fiction.

Comment: Movie is produced by Fox Star Studios and Sony is there rival studio, so why will they give free promotion to there channel in there film? And I know it's biopic but that doesn't means they have to make it exactly like the real story piece by piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments already cover that they broadcasters may well not have wanted to advertise another channel, however...

It's 2003.
Before the "everybody in the world has 147 channels" era.

TV stations didn't use to ident all the damned time. They assumed you already knew what channel you were watching. If the channel had adverts, then they would ident in and out of the ads, or between shows, but at no other time.

I understand this may not apply to the US, which was already famous back in the 80s/90s for ["57 Channels and Nothing On"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_Channels_(And_Nothin'_On)) but the rest of the world was well behind on this broadcasting plethora.

Another real world reason they had the recording without ident in the first place is that the ident is added at broadcast, so won't be on the recording itself. That way any channel can licence the recording without needing to obscure an existing ident.

Comment: I don't think this is likely. I distinctly remember the various DD logos on the Doordarshan channels, and the ESPN & Star Logos on the ESPN/Star Sports channels, and so on. However, Googling for articles from that time didn't get me any with a photo of a TV, so I can't dispute the claim.